# Construction isomorphism of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am wondering about construction isomorphy between $Stem(\mathbb{Q},x^3-2) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}  \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$. Any hint or references for that would be useful.

Comment: What's $Stem(-,-)?$

Comment: Let $f$ be a monic irreducible polynomial in $F[X]$. We say that $F[a]$ is a stem ﬁeld for $f$ if $f(a) = 0$. Then
$α \longleftrightarrow x: F[a] \rightarrow F[x]$, $F[x] = F[X]/f(X)$.

Comment: $Stem(\mathbb{Q} ,x^3-2)=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(x^3-2)=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x-\xi \sqrt[3]{2})(x-\xi^2 \sqrt[3]{2})$\\ I find this is isomorphy to $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$, but I am sure I did something wrong